# How do I maneuver the jet?

Tags: battlefield-3

I sometimes get to fly the jet on BF3 near the end of the round, and I almost always fly it out of range of the battlefield and die.

How do I turn the bird? It seems to have a mind of its own.

I have been trying the maneuver with the keys  <kbd>A</kbd> ,  <kbd>D</kbd>  and the arrow keys <kbd>←</kbd>  , <kbd>→</kbd>  in combination with  <kbd>↑</kbd>   and  <kbd>↓</kbd>  .

Comment: Just for reference, I'll go ahead and leave that changing the sticks to southpaw is (in my opinion) a much more intuitive way to control the jet. The default controls feel backwards to me, but southpaw most people can instantly figure out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<kbd>A</kbd>  and  <kbd>D</kbd>  are used to to control your *yaw* (horizontal turning), while <kbd>↑</kbd>   and <kbd>↓</kbd>   control your *pitch* (vertical turning) and <kbd>←</kbd>   and <kbd>→</kbd>   control your *roll* (rolling counter-clockwise and clockwise, respectively).

To make sharp turns, you need to roll in the direction you want to turn, while pitching upwards and at the same time (if you're not completely vertical, if you are then just keep pitching up) yawing in the same direction.

For example, to turn right, do the following: <kbd>→</kbd>   until you're almost vertical, then hold  <kbd>D</kbd>  at the same time as <kbd>↑</kbd>   (for regular flight control, for inverted flight control, just hold <kbd>↓</kbd>   instead).

Comment: Note that, if using the arrow keys instead of the your mouse, you can use spacebar to fire your guns.